# Buggy IF statement

Tags: c#, testing, if-statement, xna-4.0, operand

I have a buggy IF statement. I am trying to check if the touch is within a certain area. However, it seems to be creating an invisible touch box for the sprite, a never ending touch box to it's right and off the screen. The left and top area work fine but the X axis to the right is buggy. Here is my IF statement.

```
if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed
    && tl.Position.X >= harePlayer.Position.X
    && tl.Position.Y >= harePlayer.Position.Y
    && harePlayer.Position.X <= (harePlayer.Position.X + 52)
    && tl.Position.Y <= (harePlayer.Position.Y + 50))
```

Comment: After i reformatted the code, do you see your bug?

Comment: Hey I just logged in and it works! Thanks so much buddy. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took the liberty of reformatting your code, to avoid having a scrollbar in the question, and immediately spotted the problem:

```
&& harePlayer.Position.X <= (harePlayer.Position.X + 52)
```

This part will always be true. *(always = unless you get a new (random?) value very time you read either of these properties)*

Change it to this:

```
&& tl.Position.X <= (harePlayer.Position.X + 52)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Problem solved, real life saver.

Have a great day mate.